# Anchor Text issue in ebay listing template

Tags: ebay-design-templates

This may be simple question. But i did quite a bit research on Google, Stack-overflow & ebay for last 2 days before posting here.

## Scenario

My company sells items via ebay. I am working on a new listing template (HTML page which describes about selling item).

Please see http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/4x-SAMSUNG-CLP-680DW-680DN-CLP680-CLT-506S-CLT506-506-CLTK-506-TONER-REFILLS-/380697552903

In the listing, blue color portion is the template created by me.

## Problem

I have 5 Anchor links (PAYMENTS, POSTAGE & HANDLING, OUR LISTINGS, WARRANTY & RETURNS, CONTACT US) on top of the template, which takes customers quickly to corresponding sections on the listing.

Actually listing template itself is a html file, which we used to modify as per product spec and upload together with ebay listing. All works fine on me local PC.

Once uploaded in to ebay, Ebay amends with some wired URL and navigation doesn't work at all. In ebay, once i hoover over the link, it shows following link,

example for PAYMENT,
http://vi.raptor.ebaydesc.com.au/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemDescV4&item=380697552903&t=1376555146000&tid=-1&category=16204&seller=tonerstop&excSoj=1&rptdesc=1&excTrk=1&lsite=15#pay

I can see # tag is appended correctly. But somehow its not functioning as expected.

## Interesting Finding

Adding more complexity, this issue apparently not consistent too. Sometimes it works as well. In some situation it forms a complete different link and works. See example below.

example for PAYMENT,
http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/4x-SAMSUNG-CLP-680DW-680DN-CLP680-CLT-506S-CLT506-506-CLTK-506-TONER-REFILLS-/380697552903?#pay

But once you refresh the browser, it stops working again.

## Tried Solutions

1.Rename anchor text assuming there may be other anchor text with same name. Didn't work.
2.Tried java script. But its not supported by ebay listing.
3.Looking for slimier template on ebay to see if those working. (Still looking)

## Questions

Why its happening intermittently?
Is there any special ebay requirement for anchor texts?
Am i missing (of course) any thing here?

## More Info

Issue still exists. Did check with 20+ different vendor's listing.

Had a long chat/email communication with ebay. But couldn't get passed to a developer other than customer support team.

So no choice for me other than to remove all the anchor menus.

Comment: it seems its working now. Can you plz share the template code. i am looking for same kind of anchor based ebay template?

Comment: @RajeshKumar Sorry, our templates are too localized for our products and supplies. So i am afraid, couldn't share. Just design a HTML file using an HTML editor, remove head and body tag, you will have an ebay template. Same HTML Anchor tag is used here too. my question is about same anchor tag was working when tested in local browser but do not work when pasted in ebay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same problem and solved it by using another method:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('XXXXX').scrollIntoView(true); return false;" href="#XXX
```

etc. like a normal anchor.

Bye!